# Automating the service restart from another server in Windows server 2016

Tags: sql-server

I want to restart the services on Application server from DB server depending on the output of query.

Ex: In DB server i have written one procedure which will generate automated mail if no transaction inserted in one table.

If no transaction inserted from last 3 minutes , i want to restart the dependent service which is on another app server

Comment: Is your intent to add the app service restart to the same proc that sends the automated email? How do you execute the stored proc currently?

Comment: Exactly..I want to restart  the app service from that proc or any other way.. currently i have  scheduled a job on dB server to execute the procedure

Answer (score 1):

Although you could restart the remote application service from T-SQL using a command invoked via xp_cmdshell, I suggest this be done with a PowerShell command instead.

The PowerShell script below calls a proc and restarts a service when the return code is 1, indicating no transactions were processed. This script can be included in a SQL Server Agent PowerShell job step running under an account with permissions needed to execute the proc and restart the remote service.

```
try {
    $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Integrated Security=SSPI")
    $command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("YourDatabase.dbo.usp_CheckNoTransactions", $connection)
    $command.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
    $returnValueParamter = $command.Parameters.Add("@ReturnValue", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int)
    $returnValueParamter.Direction = [System.Data.ParameterDirection]::ReturnValue
    $connection.Open()
    [void]$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    $connection.Close()
    if($returnValueParamter.Value -eq 1) {
        Write-Output "No transactions processed - restarting application service..."
        Get-Service -ComputerName "YourApplicationServer" -Name "YourAppServiceName" | Restart-Service
    }
}
catch {
    throw
}
```

Sample proc:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.usp_CheckNoTransactions
AS
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Transactions WHERE CreateTimestamp > DATEADD(minute, -3, GETDATE()))
BEGIN
    --application has stalled - send email and return 1 to indicate a service restart is needed
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail ...
    RETURN 1;
END;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I was about to suggest something similar to Dan Guzman suggestion.

I would create a SQL job that will run the powershell script

> (only this part)  Get-Service -ComputerName "YourApplicationServer" -Name "YourAppServiceName" | Restart-Service)

and would simply add a sp_start_job in the store proc to launch it.

That way, I have the history of the service restart from the SQL Agent history.
I can also restart the service by running the job if required.
It also allow you to create a proxy for the powershell execution (in case you don't want to give that level of permission on the app server to your SQL server service account)